# C++ How to tally grade range in a file

Tags: c++, clion

Good afternoon, I'd like to preface by saying this is my first semester working with C++, so I apologize if the answers to the errors I've run into are obvious/simple to answer.

I am trying to implement a program that requests a file from a user that contains a range of grades from students (total of 20). The program asks the user for the range inputs for traditional letter grades (i.e. A = 90-100, B = 80-89, C = 70-79, etc to F), then tallies the number of grades in the input file the user provided.

As of now my program loops through each letter grade to gather the grade range from the user, but I have issues when it comes to tallying the number of grades in the file. It keeps outputting "the number of grades in this range is 29."

(Side note, my code also produces a histogram based off of the tallied number of each grade in the file. Obviously, my histogram output looks super whack at the moment because my tally function needs some fixing.)

Again, apologies if the answer to this is simple. I am very new at this and am learning as I go. Thanks for reading.

```
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

const float WIDTH     = 550.0;     // width of the window for display
const float HEIGHT    = 750.0;     // height of the window for display
const int   FONT_SIZE   =  25;     // character size
const float LEFT_X    = 100.0;     // Left X position for label
const float LOW_Y     = 700.0;     // LOW  Y position for label
const float HIGH_Y    =  50.0;     // HIGH Y position for label

using namespace std;




void readConfig() {
    int numGrades = 5;
    int maxInGrade = 20;
    string filename;

    cout << "Enter the number of possible different grades: " << endl;
    cin >> numGrades;

    cout << "Enter the maximum number of students receiving the same letter grade: " << endl;
    cin >> maxInGrade;

    cout << "Enter the filename containing the scores: " << endl;
    cin >> filename;
}

void initFrequency() {
    string letters;
    int numGrades = 5;
    int freqLetters, low, high;
    //below defines the lowest range for each grade
    int grade_range_a = 90;
    int grade_range_b = 80;
    int grade_range_c = 70;
    int grade_range_d = 60;
    int grade_range_f = 0;



    cout << "For each grade enter the" << endl << endl
         << "(1) string representing the grade," << endl
         << "(2) lowest possible score in that range, and" << endl
         << "(3) highest possible score in that range." << endl;

    ifstream infile("/Users/quinntortellini/CLionProjects/cop3014-p7-f18/cop3014-p8-f18-attempt2/resources/hist.in");
    if(!infile)
    {
        cout << "Can't open file hist.in";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int sum=0, number;

    for (int i=0; i<numGrades; i++)
    {
        cout << "Grade string: " << endl;
        cin >> letters;
        cout << "Lowest possible score: " << endl;
        cin >> low;
        cout << "Highest possible score: " << endl;
        cin >> high;
        cout << "The number of grades in this range is " << endl;

        while (infile >> low)
        {
            if (low == grade_range_a||grade_range_b||grade_range_c||grade_range_d||grade_range_f);
            counter = counter += 1;
        }
        {
            cout << counter << endl;
        }
        infile.close();
    }

}

int main() {

    int numGrades  = 5;   // number of different letter grades
    int maxInGrade = 20;  // maximum number of students in any letter grade
    string filename;      // name of input file containing scores

    // 
    // implementing readConfig, initializes numGrades, maxInGrade, and
    //                                        filename
    //

    readConfig();

    string letters[numGrades];   // each entry represents string representing the grade
    int freqLetters[numGrades];  // each entry records occurrence of grades corresponding
    // to the letter grade

    initFrequency();

    //
    //
    //
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600, 800), "COP3014 Grade Histogram");
    sf::Font font;
    font.loadFromFile("resources/arial.ttf");

    // You are free to change the following code. However, as it is, it should work
    sf::Text min, max;
    min.setFillColor(sf::Color::Yellow);
    min.setFont(font);
    min.setString("0");
    min.setCharacterSize(FONT_SIZE);
    max.setFillColor(sf::Color::Yellow);
    max.setFont(font);
    max.setString(to_string(maxInGrade));
    max.setCharacterSize(FONT_SIZE);
    min.setPosition(LEFT_X-FONT_SIZE*2, LOW_Y-FONT_SIZE);
    max.setPosition(LEFT_X-FONT_SIZE*2, HIGH_Y-FONT_SIZE/2);

    sf::RectangleShape bars[numGrades];
    sf::Text labels[numGrades];

    float x_incr = (WIDTH - 100)/numGrades;
    float x_offset = LEFT_X+FONT_SIZE;
    float height_unit_pixels = (HEIGHT - (HIGH_Y + FONT_SIZE)) / maxInGrade;

    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < numGrades; i++) {
        float height = freqLetters[i] > maxInGrade ? maxInGrade : freqLetters[i];
        bars[i].setSize(sf::Vector2f(x_incr-50, height*height_unit_pixels));
        bars[i].setPosition(x_offset+x_incr/2, LOW_Y);
        bars[i].rotate(180);
        labels[i].setFillColor(sf::Color::Yellow);
        labels[i].setFont(font);
        labels[i].setString(letters[i]);
        labels[i].setCharacterSize(FONT_SIZE);
        labels[i].setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
        labels[i].setPosition(bars[i].getPosition().x-FONT_SIZE, LOW_Y+FONT_SIZE);
        x_offset += x_incr;
    }

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
                    break;
                default:
                    window.clear();
                    window.draw(min);
                    window.draw(max);

                    for (int i = 0; i < numGrades; i++) {
                        window.draw(bars[i]);
                        window.draw(labels[i]);
                    }
                    window.display();
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x == a || b || c ...` doesn't do what you think it does. You need to do `x == a || x == b || x == c || ...`

Comment: `if (low == grade_range_a||grade_range_b||grade_range_c||grade_range_d||grade_range_f);` remove the semicolon at the end of the line for the `if` to have an effect.

Comment: You could learn a lot by searching the internet for examples.  For example, use these keywords: "c++ grades example".  There are already a plethora of grade related examples on StackOverflow.

Comment: BTW, the **local** variables declared in `readConfig` will disappear after execution leaves the function.  Either pass the variables by reference or <yuk> make them globals.  You could omit the function and paste the code directly into `main()`, eliminating the function.

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead of arrays.  If you must declare arrays, use `const` integers or `#define` macros for the array capacity.  If you want to make dynamic arrays (capacity defined at run-time), use `std::vector` or use `new` to dynamically allocate the arrays.

Comment: Hint: is 65 **equal to** any of you grade range boundaries?